# ssh giving me a permission denied!

Tags: ssh, github

I'm not exactly an expert at this, but I'm pretty sure I have covered everything here.

I wrote this :

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "tekkub@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/tekkub/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/tekkub/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/tekkub/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
01:0f:f4:3b:ca:85:d6:17:a1:7d:f0:68:9d:f0:a2:db tekkub@gmail.com
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|     .+   +      |
|       = o O .   |
|        = * *    |
|       o = +     |
|      o S .      |
|     o o =       |
|      o . E      |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Then I `pbcopy`'d the info to my github account. Saved it. Performed `ssh git@github.com` and it worked as expected.

Then I set up my config file..

Host hq
Hostname 75.101.0.93
User alorus
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
StrictHostKeyChecking no

Then I tried `ssh hq` :

```
Permission Denied
```

I did this:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Tried again.. nothing.

Tried this :

ssh-keygen -t dsa -C "tekkub@gmail.com"

created a new pub, new key, and it failed.

I ran this:

```
Gladys-MacBook-Pro:.ssh larrykain$ ssh -v hq
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/larrykain/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for hq
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 75.101.o.93 [75.101.o.93] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/larrykain/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<4096<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '75.101.0.93' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/larrykain/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/larrykain/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/larrykain/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. <strike>I don't know how specifically to perform this on github, but the key must be on the authorized_keys list.</strike>

Oops, now I see you're trying to get back to a box you control. Not a problem :)

Comment: good point. i have my main box. and yes, that works. this is me trying to put it on a secondary box where it doesn't work. i tried doing your comand on the box that didn't work.

Comment: @Trip just to be fully clear: you have the ssh private key, id_rsa, in ~/.ssh on the box you are sshing _from_. And you have the contents of the ssh public key, id_rsa.pub, in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the box you are sshing _to_. Sorry, I should have been much more clear in my answer

Comment: Michael this is  so embaressing but I was trying to ssh into a server, but uploading my .pub to github, and not to the server. I tried to delete this, but it said i had to many answers. So I wanted to give you cred for being awesome. :D~

Answer (score 0):

try `ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/{yourpublickey} username@ipmachine`

change username and ipmachine with your credential account

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any access to the server at this point?  Check the sshd logs to see why it's rejecting your key.